# Display HDMI Problems

Tags: hdmi

When I plug my PC into my Samsung SyncMaster 2032MW TV, it doesn't scale to the native 1680x1050 (16/10). It seems its been horribly programmed, in the settings menu for the HDMI input there's,

Wide - Zooms in so the sides are cut off but (kind of) fits above and below
16:9 - Letter-boxes above and below
Zoom1 - Does horrible stretching vertically, all borders of the OS are out of view
Zoom2 - Does above effect presumably twice as much
4:3 - obviously we dont want, adds side Letter-boxes

So there's no native 16:10 availability, am I doing something wrong.
There are no problems with the PC / HDMI cord/s as I tested the PC with 2 cables on my normal TV and both outputted full 1080p.
I tested using a VGA cable and it worked perfectly fine without any tweaks,  but them I have no sound which is a one of the reasons behind  choosing the TV as  display. 
I'm currently running letterboxed 1600x900 with borders around the OS.

Does HDMI not output 16:10 or is this TV just bad.

Comment: Are you sure that Windows is outputting 1680x1050? Go to Display settings -> Advanced display settings and check.

Comment: ..... I'm sure.

Comment: Check if your TV has a "PC Mode" or something similar under the HDMI settings.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Then I guess your TV just expects a 16:9 image from HDMI and applies some sort of scaling to other aspect ratios. My suggestion would be to just go with DVI-D as it is essentially the same as HDMI at that resolution.

Comment: Maybe I could apply black bars to the sides,  using the OS and output at 16:9 then use the tvs scaling features to cut out the bars so it's effectively 16:10 at full resolution,  but I don't know if it's possible to force letterbox in in Windows.